# Page-Break on HTML site in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I'm trying to make a pagebreak after a full-page div container.
Like having an introductory page on load and if you scroll down you can get to a kind of navigation center.
I feel like this could be a chrome problem but the page-break item didnt work in edge either.

I want the pagebreak after the closing tab of `<div class="pagebreak">`. The div contains a background, a small header and a big header which all fills (and should fill) a complete page. After that I want to force a new page, so that you have to scroll down independent of the screen size.

```
<body>
        <div>
            <div class="pagebreak">
                <div class="nav">
                    <nav>
                        <div class="navitem">
                            <a href="#webprogrammierung">Webprogrammierung</a>
                            <a class="name">Niclas Kusenbach</a>
                            <a href="#verteilteSysteme">Verteilte Systeme</a>
                        </div>
                    </nav>
                </div>
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="centered">
                        <h1>Mein Portfolio.</h1>
                        <h2>Entwicklung verteilter Systeme</h2>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="uebersicht">
                <div id="webprogrammierung">
                    <h3>Webprogrammierung</h3>
                    <a>Vorlesung 1</a>
                    <a>Vorlesung 2</a>
                    <a>Vorlesung 3</a>
                    <a>Vorlesung 4</a>
                    <a>Vorlesung 5</a>
                    <a>Vorlesung 6</a>
                    <a>Vorlesung 7</a>
                </div>
                <div id="verteilteSysteme">
                    <h3>Verteilte Systeme</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
```

```
.uebersicht {
  display: block;
  page-break-before: always;
  float: none;
}
.pagebreak {
  page-break-after: always;
  page-break-inside: avoid;
}
```

Comment: Do you want to have something like a parallax? Take a look at https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_parallax.asp

Comment: No I just want a picture page onload and if the user scrolls down he sees text. I'll try to get sth from the parallax page thank you!

Comment: The `page-break...` parameters in CSS are intended for printouts, i.e. `@media print`

Comment: that helped, I oriented on the sourcecode of that and adapted it for my pruposes thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I understood you right and this example will help you

try this css

```
html, body {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
    }
    .wrapper {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%; 
        margin: 0;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
    }
    
    .first {
        width: 100%;
        background-color: red;
        flex: 0 0 100%;
    }
    .second {
        width: 100%;
        background-color: blue;
        flex: 0 0 100%;
    }
```

and try this html

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="first">
        <div>Some pictures</div>
    </div>
    <div class="second">
        <div>some content</div>
    </div>
</div>
```